# Get an error when I try to pass an element to an HTTP request

Tags: objective-c, nsuinteger

error:

> collection element of type nsuinteger aka unsigned long is not an
>   objective c object

I am trying to make an http request to stripe. This is what the params look like

```
@"card": card.number, @"exp_month": card.expMonth, @"exp_year": card.expYear, @"cvc": card.cvc
```

The card.expMonth is whats causing the error. I tried adding (unsigned long) infront, but got the error

> collection element of type 'unsigned long' is not an objective c object

What can I do to send the month element?

Comment: Post the relevant code causing the issue.

Comment: I did. card.expMonth is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "code" you posted isn't very clear. But it seems that `card.expMonth` is an `NSUInteger`. You need to wrap such primitive types in `NSNumber` objects.

Do that by changing:

```
card.expMonth
```

to

```
@(card.expMonth)
```

Do this for any of the values that represent a primitive number type.